# Aggregated results without duplicates on multiple columns each filtered differently

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table that looks like this and that can't be modified:

| **Country** | **Customer** | **Number of connections** | **Number of purchases** | **Country Metric 1** | **Country Metric 2** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brazil | A | 10 | 1 | 3 | 1000 |
| Brazil | B | 90 | 5 | 3 | 1000 |
| Brazil | C | 80 | 2 | 3 | 1000 |
| Namibia | B | 20 | 1 | 5 | 2000 |
| Namibia | C | 150 | 2 | 5 | 2000 |

About this table, please note that:

- Each combination of Country-Customer is unique.
- The country metrics, as their names suggest, only depend on the country.
- For some countries, some metrics are not available (`NULL` in the table).
- For some combinations Country-Customer, the number of connections/purchases are not available

I would like to obtain, **in the same query**, the following information:

- The mean of *Country Metric 1* only taking into account combinations of Country-Customer having at least a number of purchases higher or equal than 2. In the example table, there are 3 combinations: Brazil-B, Brazil-C and Namibia-C. The mean should take into account Brazil only once so the result is `(3 + 5) / 2 = 4`.
- The mean of *Country Metric 2* only taking into account combinations of Country-Customer having at least a number of connections higher than 100. There is only one combination which meets this criterion in the example table: Namibia-C. Thus, the expected result is 2000.

Those are just examples but there can be more metrics and other aggregations (sum, min, max, count...) but they should be very similar.

Here is what I've tried:

```sql
SELECT AVG(IF(purchases > 2, country_metric_1, NULL)), -- => 6.5
AVG(IF(connections > 100, country_metric_2, NULL)) -- => 2000
FROM table
```

Issue: if the same country appears in multiple combinations, the same metric is taken into account multiple times.

```sql
SELECT AVG(IF(purchases > 2, country_metric_1_p, NULL)), -- => random
AVG(IF(connections > 100, country_metric_2_p, NULL)) -- => random
FROM (SELECT purchases, 
connections,
IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country) = 1, country_metric_1, NULL) country_metric_1_p
IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country) = 1, country_metric_2, NULL) country_metric_2_p
FROM table)
```

Issue: for each country, only one combination is taken into account giving lower and random results...

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Does the rule of Country Metric 1 that the mean should take into account a country only once apply also for Country Metric 2?

Comment: Yes! The same rule is applied for all Country Metrics @forpas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN purchases >= 2 THEN country_metric_1 END) country_metric_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN connections > 100 THEN country_metric_2 END) country_metric_2
FROM tablename 
WHERE purchases >= 2 OR connections > 100
GROUP BY country
```

you get the metrics that you want once for each country.
Use the above query as a CTE and average its results:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN purchases >= 2 THEN country_metric_1 END) country_metric_1,
           MAX(CASE WHEN connections > 100 THEN country_metric_2 END) country_metric_2
    FROM tablename 
    WHERE purchases >= 2 OR connections > 100
    GROUP BY country 
)
SELECT AVG(country_metric_1) avg_country_metric_1,
       AVG(country_metric_2) avg_country_metric_2
FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6ef13e19f7768673d3d2c16532fb26e7).
Results:

| avg_country_metric_1 | avg_country_metric_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2000 |

Comment: Thanks a lot @forpas! Do you think your solution could be adapted so that we get the averages grouped by customer?

Comment: @Katrina this is a different requirement for which you should ask a new question.